# How would you translate "¿A que adivino quién es?" in this context?

Tags: traducción

Ignoring the sentence, the context suggests it means "Who can guess who it is"? What is the actual translation?[image]
Also, are llamitas "little calls", or "little flames" or something else like an animal?

Also, what does: "vive por la Quebrada ¿ya captan?" and "sigue en Primaria" mean here?

> los demás pasajeros bajaron en la avenida Arequipa. A la altura de
>   Javier Prado subió el cachalote Tomasso, ese albino de dos metros que
>   sigue en Primaria, vive por la Quebrada ¿ya captan?;

The first I think means " is still in grade school, rather is continuing towards school. The second looks like "lives near" la Quebrada, but "ya captan" wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“¿A que adivino quién es?”  -->> I bet you that i know who it is. (in a playful manner)

the 'flamitas' would mean literally 'little flames' but in the context it's the same as saying 'i have a parched throat'

on the second text, the narrator is explaining something that happened. let's break it down

> A la altura de Javier Prado subió el cachalote Tomasso, ese albino de dos metros que sigue en Primaria, vive por la Quebrada ¿ya captan?

--> at Javier Pardo (street) cachalote(adjective comparing the guy to a whale for it'
s size) Tomasso (person), the two meter Albino, the one who still attends Primary school and lives by la Quebrada (place, usually a cliff). Do you understand yet?

Comment: Ya captan means, "Did you all get that?" or are you are asking me?

Comment: sorry! It means 'do you understand yet?'. it's slang (Mexican, i think)

Comment: "Tengo llamitas en el estómago" --> I'm thirsty (for beer, in that context --> flames in my stomach)

Comment: Miguel didn't want everyone to know who the girl is. But Tobías said "Entre los pajarracos no hay secretos" ---> is like *Don't hide that secret from us, we're all 'dogs' or 'Don Juanes' *. "A que adivino quién es" --->   Possibly Francisco and Tobías know the girl's identity and Tobías is gonna take a guess. But Rubén stop him from guessing saying that he doesn't care.